# Call to Mainform from Subform

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, subforms

I have an access database that has a form with a VBA populated date.

Each time the form loads the date is automatically populated into the textbox labeled "Date". On this same form I have a subform that links to a seperate table for calculation purposes.

I want the same date from that "Date" field to be saved in my subforms calculation table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your calculation you can reference the date control on the parent form like this  (*not tested*)

```
Me.Parent.lblDate
```

suppose you wanted to calculate 3 days ago

```
DateAdd("d",-3,Me.Parent.lblDate)
```